# Append text to file with new line c++

Tags: c++

I want to append a text from file. I already done to append a text to a new file but the text can not enter the new line. This is my code :

```
ofstream data_ip_list;
data_ip_list.open("data_ip_list.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    ifstream fileinput("ip_a.txt");
    if(fileinput.is_open()){
        for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
            fileinput >> str1[i];
            data_ip_list << str1[i] ;
```

the result :

```
192.168.0.10010.10.10.2
```

how to make this to :

```
192.168.0.100
10.10.10.2
```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a newline character `'\n'`.

```
ofstream data_ip_list;
data_ip_list.open("data_ip_list.txt", std::ios_base::app);

ifstream fileinput("ip_a.txt");
if(fileinput.is_open()){
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        fileinput >> str1[i];
        data_ip_list << str1[i] << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `std::endl` or `'\n'` to add the newline

```
data_ip_list << std::endl;
// or
data_ip_list << '\n';
```

But `std::endl` flush the output buffer, which may be a little slower than `'\n'`.